# Computer won't boot or POST

Tags: boot, motherboard, post

I'm trying to boot a config with :

MB : MSI H81i / CPU : Intel Pentium G3420 / RAM : G. Skill F3-12800CL9D-8GBRL

I have no graphics card installed (i use the motherboard integrated one).

When i power on, the CPU and CASE fans spin correctly and continually, but i've no video output (tested on VGA/DVI/HDMI and different display output) and when i plug mouse or keyboard there is no light on. And also there is no beep.

So, anyone have an idea of what could be the issue here (I wonder if the mobo isn't failing) ?

Thanks you a lot for the help (and sorry for my bad english).

Comment: It sounds like you have experienced a hardware failure.  I can only assume you have verified all your cable connections and the device at some point did indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was one of the DIMM slot which didn't work.